# Camera Update Factory is Not Initiliaze in Google Map

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-camera, google-maps-android-api-2

i had a map in my android app.....me and my friend is working on that he had created a map nd it is display in his emalutor...when i import same project in my eclipse ..nd run it gives me error that camera update factory is not initilze...but my partner is working on same map....i cant understand what is the problem in my emalutor or eclipse or any other reason..if any one know then help me

my xml file is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >    

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

i had called this from my map activity

```
MapsInitializer.initialize(this);
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main_map, frameLayout);
googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20.0f));
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Friends I Need Ur help....

Comment: have you follow the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) guild and set up all the things which include `Installing the Android SDK.` and `Configuring the app to use Google Play services`.. it sounds like the problem to me

Answer (score 0):

The getMap() method is async , your next line will be executed before the map is ready , do this:

```
 supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
          googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20.0f));
          googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
          googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        }
}
```